# android number format exception invalid int ""

Tags: android

i  am making an application in which i am using parsing code.for converting value.,but i am getting number format exception.here is my code

```
public void checkPointsResponse(String val)
{

    int points;
    progressDialog.dismiss();
     points = Integer.parseInt(val);
    if(points > 0)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(Contact_ListActivity.this,Account.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(Contact_ListActivity.this,Account_Question_Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

here is logcat image
[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: its because your `val=""` is empty.

Comment: the string value of "val" is null.

Comment: @SpringBreaker ok  sir.then what sholud i do????

Comment: @Lollipop ok  sir.then what sholud i do????

Comment: @R.T.: pass some valid integer when you are calling `checkPointsResponse()` method else you can give some checking point in the method like some below answer suggested.

Comment: @SpringBreaker ok sir  i try..thnku..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

public void checkPointsResponse(String val)
    {

        int points;
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if(val.trim().length()>0){
            points = Integer.parseInt(val);
            if(points > 0)
            {
                Intent i=new Intent(Contact_ListActivity.this,Account.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent i=new Intent(Contact_ListActivity.this,Account_Question_Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Value not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Before `Convert` your `String val` to `Integer` check val is null or not like

```
if(!val.trim().equals("")){
//Convert val to Integer and do your job
}
```

You got `Number Format Exception` because your val is null and you convert null value into Integer.

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

**Error showing because your val empty and not convert into integer .**

```
public void checkPointsResponse(String val)
                {

                    int points;
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    if(!val.trim().equals(""))// check if val empty 
                    {
                         points = Integer.parseInt(val.trim());
                        if(points > 0)
                        {
                            Intent i=new Intent(Contact_ListActivity.this,Account.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Intent i=new Intent(Contact_ListActivity.this,Account_Question_Activity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one :

```
public void checkPointsResponse(String val)
{

int points;
progressDialog.dismiss();
if(!val.isEmpty()) {
points = Integer.parseInt(val);
if(points > 0)
  {
    Intent i=new Intent(Contact_ListActivity.this,Account.class);
    startActivity(i);
  }
else
  {
    Intent i=new Intent(Contact_ListActivity.this,Account_Question_Activity.class);
    startActivity(i);
  }
 }
}
```